# Adding images at the end of google BarChart in each row

Tags: javascript, html, svg, google-visualization

How can I add images in google BarChart?

Below is the script which I did so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTrattamentoFinanziario);

    function drawTrattamentoFinanziario() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['KPI', 'Trattamento Con Presidio', 'Trattamento Assicurativo', 'Trattamento Contrattuale', 'Rischio Residuale', { role: 'annotation' } ],
            ['Credito da Banche', 10, 24, 20, 32, ''],
            ['Credito da fornitori', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Credito da terzi', 28, 19, 29, 30, ''],
            ['Credito da soci', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Fluttuazione prezzo delle materie prime', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Peggioramento condizioni di pagamento', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Rischio tasso', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Rischio credito', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Rischio cambio', 16, 22, 23, 30, ''],
            ['Altri Rischi', 16, 22, 23, 30, '']
        ]);

        var options_fullStacked = {
            isStacked: 'percent',
            chartArea:{left:"10%",top:"10%",width:"80%",height:"80%"},
            height: 550,
            bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
            legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 3},
            hAxis: {
                minValue: 0,
                ticks: [0, .3, .6, .9, 1]
            },
            series: {
                0:{color:'blue'},
                1:{color:'orange'},
                2:{color:'#888'},
                3:{color:'red'},
            }
        };
        // Instantiate and draw the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('drawTrattamentoFinanziario'));
        chart.draw(data, options_fullStacked);
    }
    </script>

    <div id="drawTrattamentoFinanziario"></div>
```

What I want to do is, adding an image/text at the end of each line based on an if condition but I dont know how to get to the end of each line for putting the image/text. The image/text should be like the second vAxis label for each line.

Comment: you can add text by using an [annotation column](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole). if you want an image, you need to use an [overlay](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays)...

Comment: @WhiteHat would you mind to show me a way for BarChart. I'm trying to figure it out but no luck. How to get the number of rows and how to set the image at the end of each row dynamically.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58346199/5090771) is an example using a ColumnChart...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you